# Do we need to use orientation media query if we are using min-width and max- width?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Do we need to still use (orientation: portrait) and (orietation:landscape) in media queries if we are using max-width and min-width?

Comment: You never *need* to use, even when not using `max-width` and `min-width`. You'll only use it if your layout needs to change according to the orientation being landscape/portrait...

Comment: @LcSalazar - the layout will always be changing from small devices to desktop so how could the orietation help over min and max width?

Comment: That's exactly my point. There maybe times when it makes a difference for your layout to know the orientation (ie the layout for mobile may expand differently when it's in landscape). But that's not always the case. It really depends on your specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It is need to be use when your designs of Landscape and Portrait versions are different. So you can add these "rules" to make it clear for your browser. If you have only one design (just some elements goes narrow in portrait version for example) it can be achieved by queries (without any orientation added)

Comment: when you say designs are different for landscape or portrait. you could still make your designs different just using media queries. I want to know a real world scenario where these would actually be helpful and how they can be better or useful than the max and min width. thanks

Comment: @user3564005 Yes - you can. but the main problem that you will be faced then - you have to restyle all styles that you had for your landscape version and this is harder isnt it? when the designs are very different. So in these situation it is better to use orientations

Comment: great. Orientations are not fully supported as much as max and min widths are right? Also, even if you use orientation, you still would be repeating the styles to make it look different.